# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity in Selenium for FirefoxDriver

Tags: selenium

I am not trying to do much here.

I am just trying to run an example given in Selenium website, to just open Google page and enter a search string in the edit box

But I get the following error:

*> Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setup(InternetExplorerDriver.java:92)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:56)
>     at
>   com.testscripts.Selenium2Example.main(Selenium2Example.java:16)*

I have no idea what this ClientProtocolException
 Class is and where to find this.

Could any one of you please help ?

Code Is

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.ie.*;

public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Vikas Kashyap\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());


        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.

I found out the mistake that I had done.

I am using Eclipse as my IDE.
In the list of externally referenced JAR files, I had included "selenium-java-2.0b3.jar"

Actually I had to include "selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar"

Selenium website doesnt really say which jar file to download for the server! This created all the confusion.

Using the right jar file, there's no more "NoClassDefFoundError" .

Regards
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the complete path to your Firefox application (with "firefox.exe" at the end) in the System.setProperty call.
Verify your classpath as well (see [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)).

Do you use the Firefox or the IE driver? You commented it out, but it looks like the error comes from another state of your code. I guess the "line 16" is the line where you instantiate your driver, is it true?